# What does s3fs cache in /tmp?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mount, s3fs

I'm using [s3fs](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) to mount a lot of files to an S3 bucket. It works fine except the fact that my local disk space is also growing a lot (the content in the /tmp directory).

My command is:

```
$ su ec2-user -c '/usr/bin/s3fs my-bucket-name -o use_cache=/tmp /home/ec2-user/dir'`
```

I'm using the `use_cache` parameter but what is actually cached? Are this files which still need to be uploaded to s3 and are cached on my local machine? Can I just delete it during upload/mount or not? And will my upload go quicker if I turn it off (if it's for other purposes)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [s3fs wiki](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/wiki/Fuse-Over-Amazon#details) (which is a bit hard to find).

> If enabled via "use_cache" option, s3fs automatically maintains a local cache of files in the folder specified by use_cache. Whenever
>   s3fs needs to read or write a file on s3 it first downloads the entire
>   file locally to the folder specified by use_cache and operates on it.
>   When fuse release() is called, s3fs will re-upload the file to s3 if
>   it has been changed. s3fs uses md5 checksums to minimize downloads
>   from s3. Note: this is different from the stat cache (see below).
>
> Local file caching works by calculating and comparing md5 checksums (ETag HTTP header).
>
> The folder specified by use_cache is just a local cache. It can be deleted at any time. s3fs re-builds it on demand. Note: this directory
>   grows unbounded and can fill up a file system dependent upon the
>   bucket and reads to that bucket.

Comment: ! what is the point of going to the trouble of mounting S3 if this stuff happens.  So if this is a 200GB SQL Server BAK file I need to have 200GB locally up my sleeve and more if SSMS thinks it is doing me a favour by reading the BAK files I was not intending to select.  I guess I am not using cache then.

Comment: You're correct. I wouldn't suggest using the cache for files that are infrequently accessed, like hopefully your .BAK files are, or primarily read from cache to s3. For pulling in frequently accessed files to a local cache, it makes sense on the write side.